# Why does this string replacement/concatenation not work in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

In this snippet of a `build.gradle` file, the first reference to  `${appengineVersion}` (line 11) causes an error. But the second reference (line 27) works fine.  Why is that?

To get it working, I've had to explicitly include the version number on line 11...meaning that I'm going to forget to update it next time. How to fix that?

```groovy
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

def appengineVersion = "1.9.48"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:${appengineVersion}"
    }
}

war {
    from 'src/main/webUI/app'

    exclude('src/main/webUI/app/node_modules')
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    appengineSdk "com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:${appengineVersion}"

    compile "javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5"
...
```

Comment: The specific error is: "Could not find property 'appengineVersion' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@6f9c2c4"

Answer (score 2):

Declaring vars on the top level of a project build file doesn’t make them visible to all Gradle blocks. `buildscript {}` is special, it gets evaluated before any other part of the script is. You can move declaration into the `buildscript` though, it should make it visible to other blocks too:

```
buildscript {
    def appengineVersion = "1.9.48"
    ...
```

but you would need to use like

```
dependencies {
    appengineSdk "com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:" + appengineVersion
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was half of the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Standard gradle practice is to declare user-defined properties in the `ext` namespace. See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:extra_properties)

You should do:

```
ext.appengineVersion = "1.9.48"
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was half of the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution was a combination of the answers from Oleg and RaGe:

Move the declaration of appengineVersion into the buildscript block AND define it in the ext namespace.

```
buildscript {
    ext.appengineVersion = "1.9.48"
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:${appengineVersion}"
    }
}
```

This allowed it variable to be resolved both by the buildscript dependency and the project dependency:

```
dependencies {
    appengineSdk "com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:${appengineVersion}"

    compile "javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5"
    compile "com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:${appengineVersion}"
```

Both answers were a key part of the solution. But unfortunately, I can't accept 2 answers, so I'm answering it myself (and up-voting both answers).